# NavLink isActive prop triggers error TS7031

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I keep getting `Binding element 'isActive' implicitly has an 'any' type)` error in my reactjs Project with Typescript. The functionality is working in production despite the `isActive` prop is being underlined, but the following error keeps showing up whenever I tried to build for production and the build failed. This is my first project with Typescript.

How do I tackle this error please?

Here is the code

```
const Header = () => {
  
  const navLink = ({ isActive }) => {
    return {
      color: isActive ? "#34C200" : "",
      fontSize: isActive ? "16px" : "",
      borderBottom: isActive ? "solid" : "none",
      paddingBottom: isActive ? "3px" : "",
      outline: isActive ? "none" : "none",
    };
  };

  return (
    <header className="shadow-md sticky z-30 top-0 bg-white px-5 sm:px-10">
      <nav className="container flex items-center py-4">
        <div className="flex flex-row sm:flex-col pl-0 sm:w-1/6 sm:mx-auto sm:justify-center">
          <img
            className="w-1/4 sm:w-2/4 sm:block sm:mx-auto"
            src="images/logos/atasp1.png"
            alt="ATASP-1 Logo"
          />
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <span className="bg-atasp-mid-red rounded-md sm:rounded-lg text-white italic text-center text-xs sm:text-md p-1 sm:px-4">
              KEBBI - SOKOTO ZONE
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul
          className={`hidden sm:flex flex-1 justify-end items-center gap-3 lg:gap-6`}
        >
          <li className="cursor-pointer">
            <NavLink to="/" style={navLink}>
              ATASP-1
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="cursor-pointer">
            <NavLink to="infra" style={navLink}>
              Infrastructure
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="cursor-pointer">
            <NavLink to="outreach" style={navLink}>
              Outreach
            </NavLink>
          </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing you need to do is add the type for isActive on the NavLink component

```
  const navLink = ({ isActive }: {isActive: boolean}) => {
    return {
      color: isActive ? "#34C200" : "",
      fontSize: isActive ? "16px" : "",
      borderBottom: isActive ? "solid" : "none",
      paddingBottom: isActive ? "3px" : "",
      outline: isActive ? "none" : "none",
    };
  };
```